# How to make WinJS.UI.ListView scale across screen resolutions and show horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: css, windows-8, winjs

What value should I set for the width property of WinJS.UI.ListView so that it scales to all screen sizes and I can make the grid view layout scroll horizontally?

If I set the width property of the div for which the data-win-control is set to "WinJS.UI.ListView" to 100% then the horizontal scroll bar does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Layout sample - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231571
WinJS ListView Deep Dive - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-108
Styling a ListView - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh850406.aspx